# Javascript class only displaying one of the objects

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am trying to console log the 'options' argument but for some reason it only shows the first object? what and how can i make it console log all of the the objects inside the 'new validator'?

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="register_username">
<input type="password" id="register_password">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
    var Validator = function (options) {
        console.log(options);
    };
    var register_username = document.getElementById("register_username");
    var register_password = document.getElementById("register_password");

    document.getElementById("register_submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var register_val = new Validator(
                {
                    element: register_username,
                    type: "str",
                    min: 1,
                    max: 20
                },
                {
                    element: register_password,
                    type: "str",
                    min: 4,
                    max: 20
                }
        );

    }, false);
```

console log

```
element: <input id="register_username" class="register_username" placeholder="Username" name="register_username" autocomplete="off" type="text">
max: 20
min: 1
type: "str"
```

Comment: You're passing two arguments, but only logging the first.

Comment: The second object is passed down as a second argument, so it makes sense that it's not part of the `options` argument since that one is the first

Comment: the other answers here are correct, change the ```console.log(options)``` to ```console.log(arguments)``` and you'll print all passed args.

Comment: May i ask why this works? why does arguments console.log both of the objects, i dont get this? i havent specified 'arguments' anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all the passed in Parameters to a function using the `arguments` Object. It is an array *like* object which has all the Parameters information which was used to call the function.` It's a javascript keyword.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

> The arguments object is a local variable available within all
>   (non-arrow) functions. You can refer to a function's arguments within
>   the function by using the arguments object. This object contains an
>   entry for each argument passed to the function, the first entry's
>   index starting at 0.

```js
 var Validator = function (options) {
        console.log(arguments);
    };
    var register_username = document.getElementById("register_username");
    var register_password = document.getElementById("register_password");

    document.getElementById("register_submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var register_val = new Validator(
                {
                    element: register_username,
                    type: "str",
                    min: 1,
                    max: 20
                },
                {
                    element: register_password,
                    type: "str",
                    min: 4,
                    max: 20
                }
        );

    }, false);
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="register_username">
<input type="password" id="register_password">
<input type="button" id="register_submit" value="click">

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped me out quite alot! i were not aware of the arguments keyword :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you either want to pass an array of options, or accept multiple options in your constructor function.

Array of options:

```
var register_val = new Validator(
    [
        {
            element: register_username,
            type: "str",
            min: 1,
            max: 20
        },
        {
            element: register_password,
            type: "str",
            min: 4,
            max: 20
        }
    ]
);
```

Constructor with multiple options:

```
var Validator = function (option1, option2) {
    console.log(option1, option2);
};
```

If you want this multiple options version but you don't know how many options will be sent, then you might want to use the `arguments` keyword to get an array of all the parameters passed to the constructor.